# How to make my fiddle work for second time input, adding objects to scene using three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js, render

I want to remove old objects and add new objects when I enter number for the second, third... times in textbox. I mean removing objects from scene and adding New objects based on new input. Working example please or edit my fiddle. Ive searched alot on Web and tried various possibilities, none helped me.

here is my working fiddle: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/sagh0900/x8n8b/4/)

Here is Sample Code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementById('txtN').value; i++) {

            var scale = 10;
            var conegeo = new THREE.Mesh(getGeometry(meshMaterial), new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(meshMaterial));
            subset.push(conegeo);
            conegeo.doubleSided = true;
            conegeo.overdraw = true;
            conegeo.position.set(i*(0.5-Math.random())*scale, (0.5-Math.random())*scale, (0.5-Math.random())*scale);
            conegeo.updateMatrix();
            conegeo.matrixAutoUpdate = false;
            scene.add(conegeo);

        }
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

I got it. I made the variables global which don't need change on every update. Now its working and included in button click:

```
if (scene.children.length > 0)
           for (var i = scene.children.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
               var child = scene.children[i];
               scene.remove(child);
               render(camera, scene);
           }
```